# Removing vowels and digits from a String in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

Remove **vowels** from the characters before the hyphen and remove any **digits** from the characters that occur after the hyphen.

I tried using this but I'm not escaping the hyphen correctly?
`s = replaceAll("[aeiou\-]", "").replaceAll("[-\0-9]", "");`

Comment: Show us what you've tried :)

Comment: Why not just do multiple passes, similar to: `string.replaceAll(vowels-before-dash, "").replaceAll(digits-after-dash, "")`?

Comment: https://codescracker.com/java/program/java-program-delete-vowels-from-string.htm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: I did s.replaceAll("[aeiou0-9]", ""); to remove all vowels and digit but I need to remove digits from the left and digits from the right. I did not know I can have multiple passes like that. Thank You!

Comment: Am I escaping the hyphens incorrectly in my code? 
s = replaceAll("[aeiou\-]", "").replaceAll("[-\0-9]", "");

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String toReplace = "magic-8ball";

    String splitChar = "-";
    String[] split = toReplace.split(splitChar);

    String replacedPart1 = split[0].replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "");
    String replacedPart2 = split[1].replaceAll("[0-9]", "");

    System.out.println(replacedPart1 + splitChar + replacedPart2);
}
```

Comment: It is usually better to add some explanation to the answer rather than just dumping a bunch of code.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="we-are-students-worker2-45man";
String regex="[aeiouAEIOU]+(?=-)|(?<=-)\\d+";
String newStr=str.replaceAll(regex, "");
System.out.println(newStr);//w-ar-students-worker2-man

//try this
```